# How to add a pop calendar?

Tags: jquery, html

I have add button it will add a startdate textbox and end date textbox along with a pop calendar.But the   calendar pop up is not working.

UPDATE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".datepicker").each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".container").append('<div class= "Cycleone"> <table> <tr> <td> <label ID="lblStartDate">Start Date </label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="txtStartDate" class="datepicker"/><label id="lblEndDate" >End Date</label></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEndDate" class="datepicker"/></td></tr></table></div>');
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
})
});
```

Button

```
<div class="button">
<input type="button" id="add" name="btnAddAddress" value="Add"  />
```

Please provide a example if possible.Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding to pop you can initialize datepicker:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    var addelement = $('<div class= "Cycle"> <table> <tr> <td> <label ID="lblStartDate">Start Date </label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="txtStartDate" class="datepicker"/><label id="lblEndDate" >End Date</label></td><td><input type="text" id="txtEndDate" class="datepicker"/></td></tr></table></div>');
    $(this).after(addelement);
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();//here
});
```

Reason: Because you are initializing datepicker on Document ready but pop datepicker is not yet present in DOM.

[**--Working DEMO--**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cubkLof/1/)

---

**Updates**

You are facing problem because when you adding input boxes you are always giving same id `txtStartDate`, `txtEndDate` even for label also. **ID** should be unique across HTML page. Just remove id from JS code:

[**--Expected DEMO--**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5gLLm0g/1/)

Comment: the method  what you said is working.But the problem is when ever i select the date in someother textbox,it reflect only in the first text box  .I have updated the code pls do see@manwal

Comment: So what do you want? When you select date from any input it should reflect only that text box.

Comment: But you can see in my demo, Its working like you want.

Comment: Can you reproduce problem on Jsfiddle? I can't assume everything :(

Comment: Yes great. Now tell me when is unexpected in this fiddle?

Comment: in the fiddle ,if you try to select the date for second set of start date and end date ,it will change in the first set of startdate and endate@manwal

Comment: One more question is it possible to add a radio button along with two text box to check wheather the text box is blank or not? @manwal